# $\sum_{k=1}^n \log k \ge \int_1^n \log x \, dx$

Tags: integration, inequality, summation

Why is

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \log k \ge \int_1^n \log x \, dx$$

is there an intuitive or graphical way to think about it?

Comment: If you write \text{log } instead of \log, then proper spacing does not appear between "log" and what precedes it unless it is added manually, just as you added in manually _after_ log.  With \log the spacing is automatically included or not depending on whether it's in a context in which that is appropriate.  It is standard usage, and I changed it. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Note that $D^{2} \log x < 0$ for $x > 0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that $\log(x)$ is an increasing function and that $\log(1)=0$, then look at the following plot:

[image]

Normally, if $f(x)$ is an increasing function, then, for $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$,
$$
\sum_{k=a+1}^bf(k)\ge\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
but since $f(a)=\log(1)=0$, we can include $1$ in the summation.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint 1:** $\int_1^n \log x \, dx =\sum_{k=2}^n \int_{k-1}^k \log x \, dx $

**Hint 2:** If $x \in [k-1,k]$ then $\log(x) \leq \log(k)$.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a picture of $\log x$ and the left and right Riemann sums corresponding to the integral with interval width $1$. Which one matches the sum on the left hand side?